# How to prove that the sum digits of repetend divide by the length of the repetend equal to 4.5?

Tags: number-theory

Let $m$ be the repetend of the reciprocal of a prime,
$k$ is number of digits of  $m$ and $k$ is even number
then the digits sum of $m$  divide by $k$ must equal to $4.5$

Sample: 
$142857$ is the repetend of the reciprocal of $7$
number of digits of  $142857$ is $6$ and $6$ is even number
digits sum of $142857$ is $27$ and $27/6 = 4.5$.

Comment: what is the repetend?

Comment: Google say : 1/7 = 0.14285714285... ( the "142857" repeats forever) so I say  142857   is the repetend for sample

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I crossposted this on mathoverflow and I think they covered the question rather nicely. Here is the [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159615/sum-of-digits-of-repeating-end-of-reciprocal-of-prime-over-period-is-frac92).